# Selecting distinct unaffected value with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to using SQL.

I have data table like this:

```
ID | code
----------
1  |  1
1  |  2
1  |  4
2  |  3
2  |  3
2  |  4
```

I need to find `DISTINCT` ID that satisfies a condition of: code associated with the ID does not equal 1 or 2.

The result should tell me that ID of 2 satisfies this condition, as ID of 1 has value of 1 or 2 in the code column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct(find records from ID and ID not have any value of 1 or 2),you then use `IN` to do it

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ID NOT IN
(
  SELECT ID FROM yourtable WHERE code IN(1,2)
)
```